# Comparing 2 tables and insert rows that doesn't fully match

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have 2 user tables that roughly look like this.

```
users_old    
| id | email          | hash | salt |
+----+----------------+------+------+
|  1 | bob@email.com  | 1234 | abc  |
|  2 | jane@email.com | 5678 | def  |
|  3 | josh@email.com | 9123 | ghi  |
|  4 | mike@email.com | 4567 | jki  |

users   
| id | email          | hash | salt |
+----+----------------+------+------+
|  1 | bob@email.com  | 1234 | abc  |
|  2 | jane@email.com | 8662 | zsq  | <--- different
|  3 | josh@email.com | 9123 | ghi  |
|  4 | mike@email.com | 4567 | jki  |
|  5 | karl@email.com | 8912 | xrz  | <--- new
```

as you can see that **users_old** contain *id*, *email*, *hash* and *salt*. however - **users** table contain the same entries + new ones at the end and some of the original entries have a different hash+salt.

What I'm looking to do is to update **users_old** table by adding new entries from **users** table AND see which entries have different hash+salt combination and add those at the end of the table also as a new entry (even though the email is the same. So the end result should be just one table

```
users_old    
| id | email          | hash | salt |
+----+----------------+------+------+
|  1 | bob@email.com  | 1234 | abc  |
|  2 | jane@email.com | 5678 | def  |
|  3 | josh@email.com | 9123 | ghi  |
|  4 | mike@email.com | 4567 | jki  |
|  5 | karl@email.com | 8912 | xrz  |
|  6 | jane@email.com | 8662 | zsq  |
```

is there a single query that can make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
insert into users_old(email, hash, salt)
    select email, hash, salt
    from users u
    where not exists (select 1
                      from users_old uo
                      where uo.email = u.email and uo.hash = u.hash and
                            uo.salt = u.salt
                     );
```

Comment: thanks, Gordon. just to clarify - the line 'select 1 from users_old'  doesn't imply that it will only check one row? there's multiple rows that might have different hash/salt

Comment: @kokozz . . . The `1` is arbitrary.  `not exists` is checking whether any *rows* are returned.  It is not considering the values in the rows.

Comment: just tried it out. works perfectly. thanks for your help!